# How to make divs side by side as well as going down the page as well

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a 'Meet the Team' intranet page, but I just can't seem to figure out the best way to do it. So, firstly, here is my code;

```
`<html>
<head>
    <h1>Meet the Team</h1>
</head>
<body>

<h3>Joe Bloggs</h3>

<div id="joe" style="position:relative;width:300px;height:350px;background-color:#959595;"> 
  <p>Test paragraph</p>

</div>

<h3>John Smith</h3>

<div id="john" style="position:relative;width:300px;height:350px;background-color:#959595;"> 
  <p>Test paragraph</p>

</div>

<h3>Jane Doe</h3>

<div id="jane" style="position:static;top:50%;float:right;width:300px;height:350px;background-color:#959595;"> 
  <p>Test paragraph</p>

</div>


</body>
</html>`
```

Now, basically the 'divs' when set to relative are all just going down the page, but I want 3 in a row and then going down in columns which will display the persons name and then a description of their role. So..

123
456
789

I've tried using the other position elements such as absolute, but it doesn't seem to work to put the divs side by side. I also want to know the best way on including the `<h3>` in the div but not having the background color on it. And finally, I know that inline CSS is probably not the best thing to use here, but I wanted slightly different background colors for each div.

Comment: [Something like this?](https://jsfiddle.net/dxjuLqss/) Otherwise I'm not sure what you're trying to get. A screenshot (quick sketch) might be helpful.

Comment: That's pretty much what I was after! But I do want a small space in between each one and then also, how would I go about doing another row like that underneath and so on? I hadn't tried using the Float element!

Comment: Try `simplegrid.css`, use 3 columns with 3 rows.

Comment: You could probably use a standard css as Jimmy suggests. [This fiddle shows another row](https://jsfiddle.net/dxjuLqss/1/). If you want to put some space in between the divs, take a look at margin and padding. A quick google search should give you plenty of info.

Comment: Thanks for your help, really useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what are you looking for?

```css
#team{
 background-color: #e7eaea;
 width: 100%;
}
#team > div{
 background-color: #a0c3ce;
 margin: 1%;
 width: 31%;
 float: left;
}
h1, h3{
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Meet the Team</title>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Meet the Team</h1>
 <div id="team">
  <div id="joe">
   <h3>Joe Bloggs</h3>
   <p>Test paragraph</p>
  </div>

  <div id="john"> 
   <h3>John Smith</h3>
   <p>Test paragraph</p>
  </div>

  <div id="jane"> 
   <h3>Jane Doe</h3>
   <p>Test paragraph</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is literally what I wanted! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do two things :

add in each div's

```
display:inline-block;
```

Secondly, its good to make a css class and use that for each div instead of copying css into all.

For example

```
<style>
    .box{width:300px;height:350px;background-color:#959595;display:inline;}
</style>
```

In HTML,

```
<div id="joe" class="box">some content here</div>
<div id="john" class="box">some content here</div>
<div id="jane" class="box">some content here</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew the way I was doing it wasn't best practice by any means! Much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome, I would like to suggest that even its one line of code but try to do as per standards.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one more solution

```css
.info {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 32%;
  height: 300px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background: orange;
}
.info h3 {
  display: block;
  background: lightgreen;
  margin: 0;
}
.info p{
  display: block;
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<h1>Meet the Team</h1>

<div id="joe" class="info"> 
  <h3>Joe Bloggs</h3>
  <p>Test paragraph</p>
</div>
<div id="john" class="info"> 
  <h3>John Smith</h3>
  <p>Test paragraph</p>
</div>
<div id="jane" class="info"> 
  <h3>Jane Doe</h3>
  <p>Test paragraph</p>
</div>
<div id="john" class="info"> 
  <h3>John Smith</h3>
  <p>Test paragraph</p>
</div>
<div id="jane" class="info"> 
  <h3>Jane Doe</h3>
  <p>Test paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add `display:inline-block;` in every `<div>`'s style

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do what you want. One is to create div 'rows' to wrap every line 3 divs:

```
<div class="row" style="width: 100%">
    <div class="col" style="width: 33%; float: left">1</div>
    <div class="col" style="width: 33%; float: left">2</div>
    <div class="col" style="width: 33%; float: left">3</div>
</div>

<div class="row"  style="width: 100%">
    <div class="col"  style="width: 33%; float: left">4</div>
    <div class="col"  style="width: 33%; float: left">5</div>
    <div class="col"  style="width: 33%; float: left">6</div>
</div>
```

Each 'col' element should be a fraction of the container (33% in this case). Yo can do it better defining a style for rows and cols:

```css
.row {
  width: 100%;
}
.col {
  width: 33%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
        <div class="col">1</div>
        <div class="col">2</div>
        <div class="col">3</div>
</div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">4</div>
        <div class="col">5</div>
        <div class="col">6</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved as shown hereby:

```
#team {
  width: 100%;
}

#team > div {
  width: 31%;
  margin: 1%;
  float: left;
  background-color:#959595;
}

<html>
<head>
    <h1>Meet the Team</h1>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="team">
        <div id="joe">
            <h3>Joe Bloggs</h3>
            <p>Test paragraph</p>
        </div>
        <div id="john">
            <h3>John Smith</h3>
            <p>Test paragraph</p>
        </div>
        <div id="jane">
            <h3>Jane Doe</h3>
            <p>Test paragraph</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But instead of applying the css you can use the twitter bootstrap which already has this implemented in a much easier way.

You can take help from the code below:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <h1>Meet the Team</h1>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
            <h3>Joe Bloggs</h3>
            <p>Test paragraph</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
            <h3>John Smith</h3>
            <p>Test paragraph</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
            <h3>Jane Doe</h3>
            <p>Test paragraph</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In this code only one row is created but you can create multiple rows and divide it into columns.

For further help refer, [1]: https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/